# Why doesn't $(this).id return the clicked element's ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does my `this.id` return undefined rather than the button's Id when clicked? I know there are slightly similar questions to this but none of the suggestions seems to work for me. Before anyone suggests, I have also tried `$(this).attr("id");`

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Meh</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <button id="warning" class="btn">Button</button>
      <p>Button id: <span id="show"></span></p>
      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js">
      </script>
      <script 
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".btn").on("click", () => $("#show").html($(this).id));
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because `this` isn't an element with an id?

Comment: Because you are using arrow function. Read about it. In this case you should use `$(".btn").on("click", function () { $("#show").html($(this).id) });
      </script>`

Comment: `$(".btn").on("click", (ev) => $("#show").html(ev.target.id));` or grab it from the event

Comment: @JordanS Thanks. Your suggestion does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way that you can do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Meh</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <button id="warning" class="btn">Button</button>
      <p>Button id: <span id="show"></span></p>
      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js">
      </script>
      <script 
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.btn').click(function(event){
            $("#show").html(event.target.id);
        });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Moose.

Comment: @CollinsOrlando, anytime!